# Stripe integration Angular and .NET 6 CORS XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/

Tags: .net, angular, stripe-payments, webapi

I make an application:

- frontend in Angular 13.2.0
- backend/web api in .NET 6
  and I try to integrate stripe payment gateway with my app. This problem bug me from a very long time and cannot find any relevant information that will help me solve this.
  Application is in development mode so it operates on localhost and wanted to develop payment functionality.

I have followed documentation from https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart and I created controller with method

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var domain = "http://localhost:4200";

            var priceOptions = new PriceCreateOptions
            {
                Product = "prod_someProd",
                UnitAmount = 2000,
                Currency = "GBP",
            };

            var priceService = new PriceService();
            Price price = priceService.Create(priceOptions);

            var options = new SessionCreateOptions
            {
                LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
            new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Price = price.Id,
                Quantity = 1,
            },
        },
                Mode = "payment",
                SuccessUrl = domain + "/payments",
                CancelUrl = domain + "/payments",
            };

            var service = new SessionService();
            Session session = service.Create(options);
            Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
            return new StatusCodeResult(303);
        }
```

When I call endpoint `[Route("api/payment")]` response is `200` and it tries to redirect to `stripe.checkout.com` with session Id but I get CORS issue

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_session_id' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5001/api/payment') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have set up CORS with

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

I also tried to set headers in controller with

```
...
            Session session = service.Create(options);
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  <--- this line
            Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
            return new StatusCodeResult(303);
```

but nothing works. I have tried to set up `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on frontend. I know that this  `header is present on the requested resource` says everything but no matter how and where I set up header it still does not make any difference.
It also has `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" Version="5.2.9" />`
Documentation of Stripe does not help at all since there is no relevant information for this problem.
So please if You any sort of information, hint for next steps it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, that was helpful. With that I was able to overcome this issue.

So here's my solution that works.

So Instead of making redirection with

```
Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
return new StatusCodeResult(303);
```

I decided to return session url

```
Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
return Ok(new { session = session.Url});
```

from stripe directly to frontend and in frontend redirect with `window.location.href`. This was it was redirected to stripe checkout page.

Once the payment is done correctly I have assigned to `SuccessUrl` query params `?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` so this was it is now `SuccessUrl = domain + "/payments?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"`

`{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` is handled by stripe so once returned to frontend it already has session_id in params. My idea was that if payment is successful then it should do something, like extend account expiration date or create an invoice or whatever. So this param allows me to check payment status.

In order to achieve that I had to check session and its' status so I catch query params on init and send to my endpoint related to stripe API.
So this is how the session status check endpoint look like

```
        [HttpGet("status")]
        public ActionResult CheckSessionStatus(string session_id)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_key";

            var service = new SessionService();

            try
            {
                var session = service.Get(session_id);

                if (session.PaymentStatus == "paid")
                {
                    return Ok(new { paid = true, status = session.Status });
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(new { paid = false, status = session.Status });
                }
            }
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { error = e.Message });
            }
        }
```

Currently I am returning only some properties from `session` but it allows to return whole `session` from stripe and check all available properties.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a 303 redirect + a `XMLHttpRequest` (or a `fetch`), this is most likely why you're getting this CORS issue.

If you follow [Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart?lang=dotnet), that isn't what they're doing:
-They're sending information with a `<form method='POST'>`
-They're redirecting with a 303 serverside

The problem with `XMLHttpRequest`/`fecth` is that it's bringing the response back from the server to the client.
If you want that to work, you shouldn't redirect serverside, you should return the session ID (e.g. as JSON), and redirect to it from the frontend using a function like `redirectToCheckout`, which you can find [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout).
(it's deprecated, but still valid - Stripe just prefers the server redirect method)

Answer (score 2):

XMLHttpRequest, similar to using fetch(), is designed to make a request, get a response back, and then you do something with the response in your code. These methods are not meant to be used with server-side redirects like you are doing here. To fix this you can either use a standard HTML form submit, or you can pass the URL back to your client and redirect client-side.